# Size difference in ArcMap and QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcmap, dimensions, size

I am working with Wildfire simulation software that creates outputs for burnt areas (rasters and shapefiles) in ArcMap. Now when I open these rasters or shapefiles in QGIS the size of the area shrinks, for example burnt area with a circle shape and a diameter of 2kms (measured in ArcMap), becomes a circle with a diameter of 1.6km when opened in QGIS.

The same goes for other data as well. For example, I created a constant value raster as a square with dimensions of 3km x 3km. But when I open this raster in QGIS it becomes a square of 2.6km x 2.6km.

I checked the CRS, they are identical in both software.
What is the problem here?

Comment: How are you measuring?

Comment: What projection are you using?